# How do I end the loop completely after I input "q"?

Tags: java, while-loop

The program does not stop after I input "q"; it still prints the random number and the sum of it. I want the program to completely stop right after I input "q".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class lab7
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    String letter = " ";
    int num = 0;
    System.out.print("Push your luck");
      */the program prints push your luck! 
    while(!letter.equals("q")){
        int sum = rand.nextInt(12);
        System.out.println(" ");
        letter = input.nextLine();
         */ the program should not print random number or sum when input "q" 
         */but in this case it does
        System.out.println("Random number: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Updated number: " + num);
        num = num + sum;
}
}
}
```

Comment: The tag was removed already, but please keep in mind that JavaScript is a completely separate language and has absolutely nothing to do with Java. As for your code, you need to exit the loop (`break;`) before printing those lines.

Comment: What do you do between reading the next line and printing the random number? (This question is a hint.)

Answer (score 1):

First give your variables meaningful names. So `num` should be `sum` and `sum` shoud be `num`. 
 
Next rearrange your code inside the loop like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();
String letter = " ";
int sum = 0;
System.out.print("Push your luck");
while (!letter.equals("q")) {
    int num = rand.nextInt(12);
    System.out.println(" ");
    letter = input.nextLine();
    if (!letter.equals("q")) {
        sum = sum + num;
        System.out.println("Random number: " + num);
        System.out.println("Updated number: " + sum);
    }
}
```

The `if` statement inside the loop prevents any further code from being executed when entered `q`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do:

```
letter = input.nextLine();
while(!letter.equals("q")) {
    int sum = rand.nextInt(12);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Random number: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Updated number: " + num);
    num = num + sum;
    letter = input.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the input to the last line of the loop, and add an input just before. That way your loop condition is always checked immediately after the input has been received.

```
letter = input.nextLine();
while(!letter.equals("q")){
        int sum = rand.nextInt(12);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Random number: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Updated number: " + num);
        num = num + sum;
        letter = input.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `if` clause which checks if q was entered and use the `break;` statement to stop it. The continue statement would also work for this case.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop should do.

```
for(String aletter = input.nextLine();!aletter.equals("q");aletter=input.nextLine()) { 
    int sum = rand.nextInt(12);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Random number: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Updated number: " + num);
    num = num + sum;
}
```

And well as you dont use the input it can be simplified:

```
while(!input.nextLine().equals("q")) { 
    int sum = rand.nextInt(12);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Random number: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Updated number: " + num);
    num = num + sum;
}
```

And if you wanted at least one output before you are able to stop it with "q":

```
do { 
    int sum = rand.nextInt(12);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Random number: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Updated number: " + num);
    num = num + sum;
}while(!input.nextLine().equals("q"));
```